# button event not working after some idle time

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

i have a simple only contains a button witch have a behind code redirect to another page

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the behind code is

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Default1 : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default2.aspx");
    }
}
```

but when i open page and wait about 15 minuets and click on the button the event is not called only it seem like refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Your session is timing out.

The **default** session timeout value in ASP.NET is **20 Minutes**.

The session timeout value can be increased in any one of the following ways:

**IIS 7**:

1. Select the website from the list of sites
2. Click on Session state on the right
3. Enter the session timeout under the cookie settings

**Add the below line** to the **Web.config** file, under the system.web section (You can change 20 to whatever value you want):

```
<sessionState timeout = "20" mode = "InProc" />
```

**Add the below line** to the  **Global.asax** file, under the Session_Start method (You can change 20 to whatever value you want.:

```
Session.Timeout = "20";
```